# Matching specific string with replace all and regex in groovy

Tags: regex, string, groovy

I'm trying to match a specific string sequence in groovy with one or many wild cards in the middle. For example:

(Where `XXXXXXXX` can be any character or number or symbol or space and can be any length)

```
String s = "What is your name? Hello my name is: XXXXXXX. Nice to meet you"

String t = "Hello my name is: XXXXXXX. Nice to meet you"

s.replaceAll("REGULAR EXPRESSION HERE THAT MATCHES THE STRING t", "My Name is Fred.");
```

This would yield the desired result of: `What is your name? My Name is Fred`.

What would be the regular expression that matches `string t`, where `XXXXXXXX` can be any character or number or symbol or space and can be any length.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is the text `XXXXXXX` the same in both string s and t ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
Hello my name is:.+Nice to meet you
```